# Frame won't show in renpy (Python)

Tags: python, renpy

I am tryign to make a game in renpy, and i implemented a small rpg like mechanic, and i was trying to show healthbars. it was working for a bit, but then it stopped and i don't know why. I checked my variables and everything seemed to be in order. maybe someone here can help me out. Below is the small rpg screen setting segment.

````
label rpg_test:
play music "Boss_Fight.wav"
$ attack = 0
if "dagger" in inventory == True:
  $ player_attack + 2
$ kdragon_hp = kdragon_max_hp
define gui.bar_tile = True 
define getting_attacked = "No one"
$ kdragon_max_hp = 50 * len(party)
$ kdragon_hp = kdragon_max_hp
screen simple_stats_screen:
    frame:
        xalign 0.01 yalign 0.05
        xminimum 220 xmaximum 220
        yminimum 100 ymaximum 100
        vbox:
            text name size 15 xalign 0.25
            text "[player_hp] / [player_max_hp] HP" size 13 xalign 0.5
            text "[player_sp] / [player_max_sp] SP" size 13 xalign 0.75
            null height 2
            hbox:
                bar:
                    xmaximum 130
                    ypos 10
                    value player_hp
                    range player_max_hp
                    left_gutter 0
                    right_gutter 0
                    thumb None
                    thumb_shadow None
                    
                null width 3
                
                

    if gilbert_in_party == True:
      frame:
        xalign 0.01 yalign 0.20
        xminimum 220 xmaximum 220
        yminimum 100 ymaximum 100
        vbox:
            text "Gilbert" size 15 xalign 0.25
            text "[gilbert_hp] / [gilbert_max_hp] HP" size 13 xalign 0.5
            text "[gilbert_sp] / [gilbert_max_sp] SP" size 13 xalign 0.75
            null height 2
            hbox:
                bar:
                    xmaximum 130
                    ypos 10
                    value gilbert_hp
                    range gilbert_max_hp
                    left_gutter 0
                    right_gutter 0
                    thumb None
                    thumb_shadow None
                    
                null width 3
    if guard_in_party == True:
      frame:
        xalign 0.01 yalign 0.35
        xminimum 220 xmaximum 220
        yminimum 100 ymaximum 100
        vbox:
            text "Guard" size 15 xalign 0.25
            text "[guard_hp] / [guard_max_hp] HP" size 13 xalign 0.5
            text "[guard_sp] / [guard_max_sp] SP" size 13 xalign 0.75
            null height 2
            hbox:
                bar:
                    xmaximum 130
                    ypos 10
                    value guard_hp
                    range guard_max_hp
                    left_gutter 0
                    right_gutter 0
                    thumb None
                    thumb_shadow None
                    
                null width 3
    if host_in_party == True:
      frame:
        xalign 0.01 yalign 0.5
        xminimum 220 xmaximum 220
        vbox:
            text "TV Host" size 15 xalign 0.25
            text "[host_hp] / [host_max_hp] HP" size 13 xalign 0.5
            text "[host_sp] / [host_max_sp] SP" size 13 xalign 0.75
            null height 5
            hbox:
                bar:
                    xmaximum 130
                    value host_hp
                    range host_max_hp
                    left_gutter 0
                    right_gutter 0
                    thumb None
                    thumb_shadow None
                    
                null width 5
                
                text "[host_hp] / [host_max_hp]" size 16
    frame:
        xalign 0.99 yalign 0.05
        xminimum 220 xmaximum 220
        vbox:
            text "Dragon king" size 22 xalign 0.5
            null height 5
            hbox:
                bar:
                    xmaximum 130
                    value kdragon_hp
                    range kdragon_max_hp
                    left_gutter 0
                    right_gutter 0
                    thumb None
                    thumb_shadow None
                    
                null width 5
                
                text "[kdragon_hp] / [kdragon_max_hp]" size 16
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fill your screen with data and it worked fine. Check the variables you have, make sure you are showing or calling the screen, that's not in the piece of code you provided: call screen simple_stats_screen or show screen simple_stats_screen. [image]